# Noncentral Chi-square distribution in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run the following line of code in R.

```
qchisq(.95, df= 166, ncp = 21731.3658)
```

I get the error:

> Warning message: In qchisq(0.95, df = 166, ncp = 21731.3658) :
>   pnchisq(x=18417.9, ..): not converged in 10000 iter.

How do I increase the number of iterations?

Comment: fwiw that's a warning message, not an error

Comment: only by hacking the C code: see https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/nmath/qnchisq.c#L78

Comment: That is one hell of an extreme NCP.I would ask why this calculation is being done? That is one seriously extreme NCP.